# Pass Angular.js binding to javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Allow me to begin by saying that I am a C++ developer by profession and have extremely poor javascript skills, so please forgive me if this is a basic question.  What I am trying to do is take a string being generated from an Angular binding and pass it to a function in javascript.  I have included an example below.  Note that I am trying to pass {{x.VodName}} to the function called "MyFunction(vodName)".  Thanks in advance!

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td><a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="MyFunction({{ x.VodName }});">{{ x.VodName }}</a></td>
<td>{{ x.Stream }}</td>
<td>{{ x.ReplayTime }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Duration }}</td>
<td>X</td>
```

```
<script>
function MyFunction(vodName)
{
    window.alert(vodName);
}
```

Comment: don't use `onClick` , use angular `ng-click` along with your function  being part of controller scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this, where your controller could look like:

```
<script>
var vapp = angular.module("vapp", []);
vapp.controller("videoController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.names = [];

    $scope.play = function(files){
      alert(files.VodName);
    };
}]);
</script>
```

and your html:

```
<table ng-controller="videoController">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td><a id="myLink" href="#" ng-click="play(x);">{{ x.VodName }}</a></td>
      <td>{{ x.Stream }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.ReplayTime }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.Duration }}</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your template you can give an variable to a function by just giving it to the function. And instead of onclick you should use [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
  <td><a id="myLink" href="#" ng-click="MyFunction(x.VodName);">{{ x.VodName }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ x.Stream }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.ReplayTime }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.Duration }}</td>
  <td>X</td>
</tr>
```

For you function in the controller it can be important to know the difference between `var MyFunction = function(name){}` and `function MyFunction(name){}`. For more about this, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)